# selectable limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

am trying to add limit of 6 selectable rows but i can't make it work. Any help!!

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".selectable").selectable({
      filter: "td.cs",


      stop: function() {
          var result = $("#select-result").empty();
          var result2 = $("#result2");
          $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {

              var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
              result.append(cabbage);
          });

          var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text();
          newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
          result2.val(newInputResult);
      }
  });
 });​
 </script>
```

I amtrying to add this source code below into the one above

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
   selecting: function(event, ui) { 
     if ($(".ui-selected, .ui-selecting").length > 4) {
       $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
     }
   }
});
```

​

Anyone?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: 'li:lt(4)',
    selecting: function(event, ui) {
        $('ui.selecting')
        $('.ui-selecting:gt(3)').removeClass("ui-selecting");
    }
});
```

For more about `:lt()`, [here](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

You don't give your html code in post. but you can try this:

```
 filter: "table.selectable > tr > td.cs:lt(4)"
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/dw6Hf/4/)**

Comment: please help me out! i am 2days now try to figure it out an i am desperatre

Comment: @user1421432 make a fiddle, so i will try to help you

Comment: @user1421432 you want to make only four element selectable? right

Comment: @user1421432 check my above demo

Comment: $(function() {
    $(".selectable").selectable({
      filter: "td.cs",
  
      
      stop: function(){
        var result = $("#select-result").empty();
        var result2 = $("#result2");
      $('.ui-selecting:gt(3)').removeClass("ui-selecting");
  $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(){
          var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
          result.append(cabbage);
        });
   
        var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text(); 
            newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
            result2.val(newInputResult); 
      }
    });
  });

Comment: @user1421432 you don't post your html, you can try my update answer

Comment: anyone who can help me pls my table is around 10.000 td?

Comment: @user1421432 please try with my new update selector for you table

Comment: you can see i cant select some of them down of the table